# rotating relative to another object

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, game-physics

I am making a [basic Three.js application](http://darkcrowz.github.io/WebGL_galaxy/)
One of my goals is to move the moon in alignment with the Earth. While I do have a method which will *statically* make it rotate in a circle, if you move around the planet the moon's rotation will start to execute oddly -- going in elliptical shapes until catching back up in a few revolutions.

the logic for it can be found in the following function:

```
rotateMoon = function(rotSpeed) {
  var x = moon.position.x,
      y = moon.position.y,
      z = moon.position.z;
  moon.position.x = x * Math.cos(rotSpeed) + z * Math.sin(rotSpeed);
  moon.position.z = z * Math.cos(rotSpeed) - x * Math.sin(rotSpeed);
}
```

my goal is to "hook" it to the earth; which is to say, it's movement is dependent on the Earth's movement. How would this be achieved?

Comment: This may be more than you need, but have you considered using a scene graph (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph)?

Comment: You're not using WebGL, you're using three.js. The answers are very different for three.js instead of webgl

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you use [THREE.js](http://threejs.org), this thing is very easy to do with it.

You can store an object like a child for another in this case Earth can be parent of Moon.

The code will be something like that below:

```js
var earth = new THREE.Mesh(e_geometry, e_material);
var moon = new THREE.Mesh(m_geometry, m_material);
moon.position.x = 100;
earth.add(moon);
```

And in update method or function:

```js
earth.rotation.y += 0.01;
```

At the THREE.js site you will found a big number of examples of this approach.

You might even take it a step further. This kind of setup is often called a *scenegraph* where each child is positioned, rotated, and scaled relative to it's parent. A scenegraph for a car might look like this

```
car
|
+--left front wheel
|
+--right front wheel
|
+--left rear wheel
|
+--right rear wheel
```

You'd do this by making the wheels children of the car. In three.js that would be

```
car.add(leftFrontWheel);
car.add(rightFrontWheel);
car.add(leftRearWheel);
car.add(rightRearWheel);
```

At that point moving the car also moves the wheels.

In the planet case though you want extra nodes so you rotate the moons around the earth and at the same time rotate the earth and the moon separately. If your scenegraph looked like this

```
earth
|
+--moon
```

The moon's orbit would be tied directly to the earth's rotation. If you do this though

```
earthBase (invisible)
|
+--earth
|
+--moonBase (invisible)
   |
   +--moon
```

Then you can rotate `earth` to make the earth rotate, you can rotate `moonBase` to make the moon orbit the earth, and you can rotate `moon` to make the moon rotate.

To make `earthBase` and `moonBase` use something like

```
var earthBase = new THREE.Object3D();
var moonBase = new THREE.Object3D();
```

Then setup the hierarchy

```
earthBase.add(earth);
earthBase.add(moonBase);
moonBase.add(moon);
```

Set the radius of the orbit of the moon with

```
moon.position.z = radiusOfMoonsOrbit;
```

Make the moon orbit with

```
moonBase.rotate.y += angularSpeedOfOrbit;
```

Make the earth and moon rotate with

```
earth.rotate.y += earthRotationalSpeed;
moon.rotate.y += moonRotationalSpeed;
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/uY8Ce/